# How to force deiconify to restore tkinter root window to original size?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to temporarily hide my tkinter root window while a certain lenghty process is executed. I understand `withdraw` and `deiconify` can be used for this purpose. My code starts with

```
root=Tk()
root.wm_title("Root Window")
root.geometry('1500x1000')
root.withdraw()
```

When my process concludes, I want the root window to appear after which I will create a new frame within it. The command `deiconify` reproduces my root window with default dimensions, not those given above. I then tried

```
root.deiconify()
root.geometry('1500x1000')
```

This restores my root window to its original size, but there is a brief flicker when the root first appears in default size before switching to the desired geometry. It's that flicker I'm trying to eliminate. It could be that the problem stems from the lengthy process carried out between the `withdraw` and `deiconify`, but I'm wondering if there's a quick fix.

Comment: I created a custom class that inherits from `Tk`, and that calls `withdraw()` when it is clicked. I then used the `after()` method to call `deiconify()` and `geometry()` after 3 seconds. The window returns properly, and it doesn't flicker. I'm using a Linux (Ubuntu); what system are you on?

Comment: I'm on a Mac (11.6.1).  Your approach sounds interesting. How lengthy is it?

Comment: 21 lines total, 15 if you remove the empty separator lines and the `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement.

Comment: I'd love to have a look.

Comment: Okay, I'll post an answer here. I'll probably have to delete it, so just let me know as soon as you have the code copied. Just for the record, it would have been easier for you to provide a [example], and then I would be able to correct you in the context of your visible code, not my invisible code.

Comment: By the way, what's this "lengthy process"? Is it in your code, or is it something `tkinter` is doing?

Comment: Highly user dependent. I will edit code above.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of a minimal reproducible example. All of this involved the MNE eeg signal processing package. I will leave the question as originally posted for now and hopefully get my act together with a better explanation. So sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: No worries! The reason I'm here on SO is so that others can take up my time ;-).

Comment: Why don't you change the geometry before deiconify?